# How to create stylized cloud streaks like these using a particle system?

Tags: node-editor, particles, shaders, eevee-render-engine

[image: Cloud Streaks Using Particle System]

I have attached a sample picture from Matkovski Dragos' project "Illustrat3d Nature". I looked up for the workflow to create clouds like these, but I didn't have any luck with that. The only thing Dragos mentions about the clouds is that they are created using a particle system to create infinite variation.

I am assuming we use emitter particle system to create these, but I am relatively new to this topic so I could be wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[I am using Eevee rendering engine]

**Edit:**

Added my shader setups for world and volumetric fog.

[image: World Shader Setup]

[image: Fog Shader Setup]

Comment: That looks like the job for some sort of noise texture set up as world shader background, not a particle system

Comment: Can you help me with the node setup? I have already created a simple gradient background and volumetric fog, but I have never used noise texture before.

Comment: It does not look like a lot of clouds, how about drawing or modeling them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use some sort of *Musgrave* or *Voronoi* texture to form the base clouds, then mix up texture coordinates with a *Noise texture* to distort them into something more irregular.

Squash the textures in Z, or stretch in XY to get the elongated look.

[image]

Comment: Your method works perfectly. I was also able to combine it with my gradient shader setup using a mix shader. Thank you!